# ACCESS DENIED with line 3 on jquery-1.7.1.min

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

```
function(a){return f.nodeName(a,"iframe")?a.contentDocument||a.contentWindow.document:f.makeArray(a.childNodes)
```

This is the offending line from IE9 script debugging

I am using **jquery-1.7.1.min**

Testing with IE9 (32-bit) on Windows 7 (64-bit)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Hitachi Password Manager</title>
    <!--- CSS --->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
    <!--- jQuery --->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min"></script>
    <!--- Javascript libraries (jQuery and Selectivizr) used for the custom checkbox --->
    <!--[if (gte IE 6)&(lte IE 8)]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="selectivizr.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="IE7.js"></script>

        <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="fallback.css" /></noscript>
    <![endif]-->

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var isIFrameLoad, myPassword;

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#hitachiIFrame').load(function () {
                //alert('loaded!'); 
                isIFrameLoad = true;
            });
            $("#container").load("login.html");
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="overlay" style="display:none;">
        <div style=" filter: Alpha(Opacity=80); opacity:0.7; width:100%; height:100%; background-color:white; top:0; position:absolute;" >
            <center><img src="images/loader.gif" /></center>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="container">
    </div>
    <!-- <iframe id="hitachiIFrame" src="test/test.html" /> -->
    <iframe id="hitachiIFrame" src="#" height="0px" width="0px"/>
    <div id="footer">
        copyright(c) 2012 Company Name
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I also did replace one line (the script line) with this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
```

I still got errors saying access denied but it was a different line number

Comment: It's all about context. And you're not providing any!

Comment: Trying with the non-minified version might be better :). Also, what are you using it for?

Comment: I don't know where 2 begin. How do I trace this to the offending method in the source file?

Comment: The real problem isn't the source file, it's what you're trying to do with it. By any chance, are you trying to manipulate data inside an iframe from another domain?

Comment: @Blazemonger I am trying to "write" data in text fields on another sub domain. Example apple.banana.example.com is the site in my iFrame but my local PC is connected to PC123456.oranges.example.com

Comment: Well, there you are then: Cross-domain issues.

Comment: Is there any way around this? The Top Level domain is the same (example.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.frames[1].document.getElementBy…
```

This should help you.